# Is it possible to post to Facebook without using Facebook Connect dialogs?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I would like to post updates to Facebook from my iPhone application. I know that there is a Facebook Connect project, but it requires displaying dialogs for entering user's credentials, dialog for posting content, etc. I would like to be able to get the credentials from application settings and post whatever the user put into UITextView.
Is it possible? or am I stack with Facebook Connect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Facebook Connect to authenticate and let the user set privacy settings for your app on their profile.  You might technically be able to write all the authentication code yourself (see [Facebook's Developers page about authentication](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/How_Connect_Authentication_Works)) but why bother when the experts have done it for you?

You can then use the Facebook Connect API to do whatever you need to do with Facebook, assuming the user has give your app permission to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately using Facebook Connect changes the behavior and the design of my application (dialogs popping out, etc.). This is why I would like to be able to send updates without these dialogs and have my own dialogs (consistent with the whole app design) for entering user's credentials and update content.

Comment: @Jakub, have got the solution ?

Comment: @Robin, unfortunately not yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jakub, Have you got solution, actually i also want to use my dialog box instead of facebook login dialog box. pleae reply..